# Grouping processes with gproc

Tags: erlang

I'm looking to group processes in an erlang application using gproc. I am new to erlang and gproc. I want to store a list of process Ids with the key being a group name. So group name "X" has many processes.

So in theory I think my registry would look like this, is it possible?

[[{n,l,group_name},<0.272.0>,<0.318.0>], [{n,l,group_name},<0.272.0>,<0.344.0>]]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to register several processes with the same key (the group name in your case), you can not use the `n` (name) type for the key. Name keys only allow one process per key.

Use the `p` (property) type instead, it allows multiple values per key.

Example:

```
gproc:reg({p, l, GroupName})
```